# Text codifying using (s,c) dense code

Tags: python, text, encoding

I am trying to codify text using (s,c) dense coding. I have found this encoding algorithm and I would like to translate it into PYTHON, but I can't understand what codeword command does (e.g. `code[p].codeword[k-1]=c+(paux % s)`).
What does code mean? Is it an empty string at the input moment? (`def encode(code,n,s,c):`)

```
def encode(code,n,s,c):
    firstkbytes <-- 0;
    numkbytes <-- s;
    p <-- 0;
    k <-- 1;
    while p<n
        paux <-- 0
        while (p<n) and (paux<numkbytes)
            code[p].codeword[k-1] <-- c+(paux mod s);
            paux <-- paux div s;
            for i <-- k-2 downto 0
                code[p].codeword[i] <-- paux mod c;
                paux <-- paux div c;
            p <-- p+1;
            paux <-- p-firstkbytes;
        k <-- k+1;
        firstkbytes <-- firstkbytes + numkbytes;
        numkbytes <-- numkbytes x c;
```

Comment: What language are you translating from?

Comment: From delphi, I think. I am not sure because I found it on a paper and it was not mentioned.

Comment: I think Delphi uses `=` for assignment. It could be some kind of pseudocode, but it's not clear what `codeword` means. Could you post a link to the paper?

Comment: http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/ir06.pdf
page 15

Comment: The algorithm in Figure 2 is not written in any actual code. The codewords appear to be generated based on the appearance of words in the vocabulary - see Table 1 for the codewords for the first ten most frequent words.

Comment: That is what I had understood, but I don't know how I could programm it...Any help will be useful. Thanks